# I am using a method getNumberOfMaxParam to find the position of the maximum of three numbers. How do I find position?

Tags: java

I am using a method named `getNumberOfMaxParam` that takes three integer numbers and returns the position of the first maximum in the order of the method parameters.

Problem: I don't know how to find position of maximum from 3 numbers and I do not want to print maximum out, I only want to print the position of maximum

The method should return 1, 2 or 3

Sample Input 1:
12 3 12

Sample Output 1:
1

Code: (Output at bottom)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class App {
    public static int getNumberOfMaxParam(int a, int b, int c) {
        int firstMax = Math.max(a, b);
        int highMax = Math.max(firstMax, c);
        return highMax;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int a = scanner.nextInt();
        final int b = scanner.nextInt();
        final int c = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print(getNumberOfMaxParam(a, b, c));
    }
}
```

Input:
1
7
8

Output:
8

I do not want to print 8 which is the maximum but instead I want to print 3 as that is position of maximum (8)

Thanks and sorry if I over-complicated this. :)

Comment: Why don't you push all input integer into array and `getNumberOfMaxParam` accept array as input. Like `getNumberOfMaxParam(int[] arr)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use arrays to store value and then find out the max number with its index

```
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] nums = new int[3];
    nums[0] = scanner.nextInt();
    nums[1] = scanner.nextInt();
    nums[2] = scanner.nextInt();


    System.out.print(getNumberOfMaxParam(nums));
    }
     
  public static int getNumberOfMaxParam(int[] nums) {

    int maxValue = nums[0];
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] > maxValue){
            maxValue = nums[i];
            index = i;
            }
        }
    return index+1;
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You found the highest number. Now compare it with the method parameters to find which of them it is and return its position.

```java
public static int getNumberOfMaxParam(int a, int b, int c) {
    int firstMax = Math.max(a, b);
    int highMax = Math.max(firstMax, c);
    if (a == highMax) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (b == highMax) {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (c == highMax) {
        return 3;
    }
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Something strange here.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this method but I am getting an error that says something like "getNumberOfMaxParam must return int value."

Comment: @ZKcoder I compiled and ran the code without error. I can only assume that you have modified it and hence you are getting a compile error. The last `else` throws an exception, since without that, you indeed get a compile error. If you don't want to throw an exception, consider returning a default value, like 1 (one) or a value that indicates a maximum was not found, for example -1 (minus one) Since the last `else` is only to satisfy the compiler, and it should never really get to the last `else`, I decided to throw an exception to indicate an exceptional situation.

Comment: Can I not return null?

Comment: @ZKcoder `int` is a primitive. A method that returns `int` cannot return null.

Answer (score 0):

If you have those three values, I would probably do it like this. Essentially just comparing the values and tracking the index with it. If something is higher than the current maximum, set the new current maximum as well as the highest index.

```java
public static int getNumberOfMaxParam(int a, int b, int c) {
    int currentMax = a;
    int highestIndex = 1;
    if (currentMax < b) {
        currentMax = b;
        highestIndex = 2;
    }


    if (currentMax < c) {
        currentMax = c;
        highestIndex = 3;
    }

    return highestIndex;
}
```

I am going to assume that you are starting to learn programming so this might be a little much but here goes:

If you want to make things a little easier to use and allow for more parameters, you could use this:

```java
public static int getNumberOfMaxParam(int... values) {
    if (values.length == 0) return 0;

    int highestIndex = 1;
    int currentMax = values[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] > currentMax) {
            currentMax = values[i];
            highestIndex = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return highestIndex;
}
```

To explain what's happening:

`int... values` defines an int array (a list of values) of variable length (that's what the three dots are for). That allows you to call the function with as many arguments as you like. For more information on that, look up "Java Varargs".

So now we have a list of values and we can follow a simple set of steps to get the index of the highest value:

1. Define base values (a starting highest index of 1 and as current maximum the first value in the array (`[0]` accesses the element at index 0 which is the first element)
2. Loop through the remaining values
3. Compare the value of the current iteration with the current maximum
4. If that value is higher than the current maximum, update it as well as the current highest index
5. Repeat 3 and 4 for all values
6. Return the highest index

You can have a look at this solution in a little ideone [here](https://ideone.com/XF1j2y) if you like!